# django- how can i save data in redis with django with custom key?

Tags: django, django-redis

i want to delete some specific data after model.save() fired.
i use "post_save()" signal.
when I use cache_page() decorator in my views.py, data will save in redis with keys like this: "prefix:1:views.decorators.cache.cache_header..8ce4de6051c3ba05396ff670741d3172.fa-ir.IRST'.

I want to save data with custom key that i specify.
how can i do it?

or

how can i delete stored data that are related to specific url ?

```
url1: a/1/b/
url2: a/2/b/
```

how can i get data that are saved for url1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default function responsible for transforming cache key looks like this:

```
def make_key(key, key_prefix, version):
    return ':'.join([key_prefix, str(version), key])
```

via [cache docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/cache/#cache-key-transformation)

So you would have to add key_prefix to your [cache_page decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/cache/#cache-key-prefixing)

```
@cache_page(60 * 15, key_prefix="site1")
    def my_view(request):
    ...
```

Comment: Ok, so I answered to the first part of the question (how to specify custom key), but unfortunately, I can't think of the way how you can achieve the second part. I'll leave the answer as it is.